# Unable to access aws s3 from docker container. ECONNREFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I'm trying to access aws s3 from a docker container. IAM role with AWSS3FullAccess is created and credentials are set using json config file.

Inside the code reading config as

```js
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config/credentials.json');
```

However, when code runs getting following error:

```
Error downloading file from s3
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '169.254.169.254',
  port: 80,
  time: 2020-01-25T07:42:31.329Z,
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '169.254.169.254',
     port: 80,
     time: 2020-01-25T07:42:31.328Z,
     originalError:
      { message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error',
        errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
        code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '169.254.169.254',
        port: 80,
        time: 2020-01-25T07:42:31.328Z,
        originalError: [Object] } } }
```

When the same code is executed without docker container and config file is provided as above, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out I was instantiating S3 client before configuring aws credentials. Although, aws credentials are global, however, seems nodejs sdk requires setting credentials before instantiating clients.